# Could you explain why typescript guard doesn't work

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

With Typescript 3.1 I have got a following piece of code

```
type Variable = string[] | File;

function isFile(variable: Variable): variable is File {
  return (variable as File).name !== undefined;
}

function getFileFromVariables(entity: EntityInterface) {
   return isFile(this.state.variables[entity.variable])
           ? this.state.variables[entity.variable]
           : undefined;
}

const file = getFileFromVariables(someEntity);
```

Unfortunately, I don't know why the file is
`const file: string[] | File | undefined`
instead of `const file: File | undefined`

Could someone tell me why it's like this and how may I fix it?

Comment: Hi. What do you want to achieve? And what do you mean by this: "`the file is const file: string[] | File | undefined instead of const file: File | undefined`". In my setup `file` has type `any`.

Comment: What is the type of `this.state.variables`?

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript isn't able to link together two instances of `this.state.variables[entity.variable]` - one that is passed into type guard and another used afterwards. For it, this is two unrelated queries into array, since `entity.variable` could be very well changed by some undercover process (or even by the type guard, if it is in the same scope), and type system isn't able to catch that.

A common workaround is to use the temporary variable:

```
type Variable = string[] | File;

function isFile(variable: Variable): variable is File {
  return (variable as File).name !== undefined;
}

function getFileFromVariables(entity: EntityInterface) {
   const variable = this.state.variables[entity.variable];
   return isFile(variable) ? variable : undefined;
}

const file = getFileFromVariables(someEntity);
```

---

Side note: try to provide a *self-contained* example, in other words, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code was impossible to check, since we don't know neither what `EntityInterface` interface looks like nor what is `this` or `this.state`. My answer is assuming that `this.state.variables` is of type `Variable` and `EnintyInterface extends {variable: number}`, and it's enough for the code provided to give you the result you ask, but please, don't force us to do this assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague.

Other than that, all the problems you are encountering are from non-strict mode and some other poor practices. I suggest you the following:

- Add `"strict": true` to `compilerOptions` of `tsconfig.json` (at least temporarily, until you figure out the solution to your problem)
- Define explicitly what you want to get from a function e.g. `getFileFromVariables(...): File | undefined`
- If possible, don't use classic functions for such cases. Instead define a type `type GetFileFromVariables = (ent: EntityInterface) => File | undefined`, then `const getFileFromVariables: GetFileFromVariables = () => ...`

Then everything instantly becomes much clearer to you.